# On the priority of arithmetic operations

Tags: arithmetic

Could someone explain the difference between these two problems:
 `6:2(2 + 1)` and `6/2(2 + 1)`?

The first one should be read as $$\frac{6}{2(2 + 1)} = \frac{6}{6} = 1$$ while the second is actually $$\left(\frac{6}{2}\right) \times (2 + 1) = 3 \times 3 = 9.$$ Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

First observe $6/2(2+1)$
If you make all brackets you get $(6/2)\cdot (2+1)$ like you wrote it.

Now we observe $6:2(2+1)$
I never saw this notation before but if you read it as a fraction you implicit make brackets around the nominator and denominator. i.e. $(6):(2\cdot (2+1))=(6)/(2\cdot (2+1))$
Now you see that don't have the same brackets and therefore you can get different results.

$6/2(2+1)=9$

$6:2(2+1)=1$

Answer (score 0):

The use of the colon sign to denote a ratio is a distraction. In the first problem you are dividing by everything and in the second example you are not. This can explicitly be seen if double parentheses were used instead of the colon.
**First Problem**
$6:2(2+1)\rightarrow 6/(2(2+1))=\frac{6}{2(2+1)}$

**Second Problem**
$6/2(2+1)=6/2*(2+1)=\frac62 *(2+1)$

**TLDR** - The colon notation is not standard in arithmetic to be used like that so double parentheses should have been used to be more explicit.